# Sorting by group is not working wordpress sql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting

Seems like sorting by group is not working on this one.

The variable $check_all is used to shown all the properties.

```
$check_all=$wpdb->get_results("select distinct town_village, suburb, state from $table where (concat(suburb,', ',state,', ',postcode)='$value' or concat(suburb,', ',postcode)='$value' or concat(suburb,', ',state,' ',postcode)='$value' or concat(suburb,', ',state)='$value' or CONCAT(town_village,', ',state) like '%$value%') Group by suburb,town_village,state", ARRAY_A);
```

Then I have this code to filter the output by searched inputted.

```
$sql_keywords.= "properties.town_village in ('".$check_all[0]['town_village']."') AND properties.state in ('".$check_all[0]['state']."') AND ";
```

As example the results must be like this all suburb 'Manila' must show first.
Please see screenshot http://prntscr.com/inpgjn

But the result I'm getting is in random. The search suburb was shown in random places in results.

EDITED: Here is the current result of the code I shown above

Search by 'Manila'
http://prntscr.com/inppj8

The result I want when they search 'Manila' is to show all the Manila at first of the results http://prntscr.com/inpgjn

Please see code for the this function

```
function lookup_string($value, $sql_keywords, $sur_suburbs='0'){
        global $wpdb;
        $suburb_region=$wpdb->get_results("show columns from suburb_region");
        $table=($suburb_region)?'suburb_region':'properties';
        if($sur_suburbs==1){
            if(strpos($value,',')!==false){
                $check_all=$wpdb->get_results("select distinct town_village, suburb, state from $table where (concat(suburb,', ',state,', ',postcode)='$value' or concat(suburb,', ',postcode)='$value' or concat(suburb,', ',state,' ',postcode)='$value' or concat(suburb,', ',state)='$value' or CONCAT(town_village,', ',state) like '%$value%') Group by suburb,town_village,state", ARRAY_A);
                $check_suburb=$wpdb->get_var("select distinct suburb from $table where CONCAT(suburb,', ',state, ', ',postcode) like '%$value%'");
            }   
            if($check_all){

                $sql_keywords.= "properties.town_village in ('".$check_all[0]['town_village']."') AND properties.state in ('".$check_all[0]['state']."') AND ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected order of query shown below. Right now I'm getting suburb in random.

---

```
suburb | state |
----------------------
Manila | Metro |
Manila | Metro |
Manila | Metro |
Manila | Metro |
Pasay  | Metro |
Makati | Metro |
ETC    | Metro |
```

Comment: "Sorting by group" - there's no sort by in your query?

Comment: I added it at $check_all last part 'Group by suburb,town_village,state' don't know if I done it right...

Comment: you code ins not complete and  ..and your question is not clear  .. if you have an error show the code really related  and the error message

Comment: @scaisEdge actually I'm not getting any error it shows the result in random but not showing it as I want to be...Please see screenshot from the question. That's what I want the result will be..

Comment: then show the code also for the "supposed" order  ..and show the expected  result and you actual result

Comment: @scaisEdge please take a look I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Still no "sort by"...?

Comment: Also - this code is wide open to [SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)....  You should be using [$wpdb->prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) on your queries.

Comment: hi @cale_b can you enlighten me on "sort by"

Comment: [GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) **does not** sort.  If you want sorting, you need to use [ORDER BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-sorting/)....

Comment: @cale_b Correct me if I'm wrong "order by" can only be sort by "asc and desc" right? if that's the case can I use it in my scenario?

Comment: Your question, with screeenshots, does not help us.  Only you know what the sort order needs to be.  How about you give us a sample output of what you expect from your query, meaning sample "order".

Comment: Hi @cale_b I added the order I want to be..Does it make sense?

Comment: @KirkBeard yes you are right Manila first and the other rows order doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to force a specific result to be first in the sort order is by using a [CASE](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2015/07/08/order-by-case/) statement in your `ORDER BY` clause, like so:

```
ORDER BY CASE `suburb`
    WHEN 'Manilla' THEN 'aaaaaaaa'
    ELSE `suburb` END, `state`
```

Here's your function, with several revisions in it:

1. Used $wpdb->prepare to use the "WordPress way" of [preventing SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753146/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-wordpress).
2. Gave the code some formatting (spacing) to help readability.  This is [recommended by WordPress also](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/).
3. Used UPPERCASE for reserved words in SQL (SELECT, FROM, OR, CONCAT, etc) also to help readability.
4. Used UPPERCASE for TRUE / FALSE, etc. in PHP.
5. Switched your condition to [Yoda style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) for defensive coding.
6. Use [$wpdb->get_row()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) for `$check_all`, since you only cared about the first result / row.

your code, modified:

```
function lookup_string( $value, $sql_keywords, $sur_suburbs = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $suburb_region = $wpdb->get_results( "SHOW COLUMNS FROM suburb_region" );
    $table=( $suburb_region ) ? 'suburb_region' : 'properties';

    if( (int)$sur_suburbs ) {
        // Your use of $check_all below will throw notices without this
        $check_all = FALSE;
        if( FALSE !== strpos( $value, ',' ) ) {
            // this is how you format "LIKE" queries using $wpdb->prepare
            $like = "%{$value}%";

            // To prevent SQL injection, use $wpdb->prepare
            $prepared = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT distinct town_village, suburb, state 
                FROM {$table} 
                    WHERE (CONCAT(suburb, ', ', state, ', ', postcode)=%s 
                    OR CONCAT(suburb, ', ', postcode)=%s 
                    OR CONCAT(suburb, ', ', state,' ', postcode)=%s 
                    OR CONCAT(suburb, ', ', state)=%s 
                    OR CONCAT(town_village, ', ' ,state) LIKE %s) 
                    GROUP BY suburb, town_village, state 
                    ORDER BY CASE `suburb`
                        WHEN 'Manilla' THEN 'aaaaaaaa'
                        ELSE `suburb` END, state",
            $value, $value, $value, $value, $like);
            // execute the prepared query
            // Use get_row to get a single row
            $check_all = $wpdb->get_row( $prepared );

            // To prevent SQL injection, use $wpdb->prepare
            $prepared = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT suburb FROM $table WHERE CONCAT(suburb, ', ', state, ', ', postcode) LIKE %s", $like );
            // execute the prepared query
            $check_suburb = $wpdb->get_var( $prepared );
        }  

        if( $check_all ) {
            // modified $check_all to use object notation, since using get_row above
            $sql_keywords.= "properties.town_village IN ('". $check_all->town_village ."') AND properties.state IN ('" . $check_all->state . "') AND ";
        }
    }
}
```